# How to prove that $\hat{0}$ belongs to vector subspace when the field is not a set of numbers?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. Let $\hat{0}$ represent the zero vector that belongs to $V$, i.e.,

- For all $\hat{u} \in V$, we know that $\hat{0} \in V$ satisfies $\hat{u} + \hat{0} = \hat{0} + \hat{u} = \hat{u}.$
- Given $\hat{u} \in V$, there exists the additive inverse $\hat{v} \in V$ such that $\hat{u} + \hat{v} = \hat{0}$.

Let $W$ be a nonempty subset of $V$ such that $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, i.e.,

1. If $\hat{x}, \hat{y} \in W$, then $\hat{x} + \hat{y} \in W$.
2. If $a \in F$ and $\hat{x} \in W$, then $a\hat{x} \in W$.

How can we now prove that $\hat{0} \in \hat{W}$?

Most similar questions and proofs I found seem to use the simple argument that $0 \in F$, so by the 2nd point above, $0 \hat{x} = \hat{0} \in W$ but I don't think this argument works in the above context because the elements of $F$ may not be numbers.

So if we do not assume $F$ to be a set of numbers, can we still prove that $\hat{0} \in W$? If yes, how can I make such a proof?

Comment: Any field by definition contains a zero element. Maybe it's not the "usual" number $0$ that we have in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, but this zero element still has the same properties.

Comment: @Mark So how do we go from the zero element of $F$ (let us call it $\tilde{0}$) to saying that $\tilde{0} \hat{x} = \hat{0}$? The field operations do not seem to have anything that could be applied to a vector space. Or is there something like that?

Comment: From the axioms of a vector space it follows that $\tilde{0}\hat{x}=(\tilde{0}+\tilde{0})\hat{x}=\tilde{0}\hat{x}+\tilde{0}\hat{x}$. Adding $-\tilde{0}\hat{x}$ to both sides gives $\tilde{0}\hat{x}=\hat{0}$. So yes, it's not immediate, it requires a proof. (but it's a short proof, as you can see)

Comment: @Mark Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Mark's comment helped me to get an answer.

Let $\tilde{0}$ be the additive identity element of the field $F$. By closure of scalar multiplication in vector space, we know that for all $\hat{v} \in V$, we have $\tilde{0}\hat{v} \in V$.

We also know that $\tilde{0} + \tilde{0} = \tilde{0}$ because $\tilde{0}$ is the additive identity of $F$. So write

$$\tilde{0}\hat{v} = (\tilde{0} + \tilde{0})\hat{v}.$$

By distributivity of scalar sum in vector space, write

$$\tilde{0}\hat{v} = \tilde{0}\hat{v} + \tilde{0}\hat{v}.$$

Let $\hat{u} \in V$ be the additive inverse of $\tilde{0}\hat{v}$. Add $\hat{u}$ to both sides to write

$$\tilde{0}\hat{v} + \hat{u} = \tilde{0}\hat{v} + \tilde{0}\hat{v} + \hat{u}$$

and then by associativity of vector sum, write

$$\tilde{0}\hat{v} + \hat{u} = \tilde{0}\hat{v} + (\tilde{0}\hat{v} + \hat{u}).$$

Since $\hat{u} \in V$ is the additive identity of $\tilde{0}\hat{v}$, we have $\tilde{0}\hat{v} + \hat{u} = \hat{0}$. So write the above equation as

$$\hat{0} = \tilde{0}\hat{v}.$$

We've shown that for all $\hat{v} \in V$, we must have $\tilde{0}\hat{v} = \hat{0}$.

Now consider $W \subseteq V$ such that $W \ne \phi$ and $W$ is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. Let $\hat{w} \in W$. Since $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication, we get

$$\tilde{0}\hat{w} = \hat{0} \in W.$$